Removing a built-in desk from my wall
I recently purchased a house that has a room I'm planning on turning into an office space. The room came with a long desk that seems to be glued to the wall of the room. Any advice in terms of how I can best remove the desk and then repair the wall? I have no experience in this area so I appreciate any and all help. For example, how should I remove the desk?, what tools should I use?, what can I do to fix the wall after that?, etc.
Here is what the situation looks like:





The stuff on the edges is caulking.  It is sticky, but usually a thin sharp knife/razor blade will cut though it.
The cabinets and maybe the top will probably also be screwed to the wall.
Once the caulking is sliced and all the screws are removed, the desk should pull out.
